# How to display object properties in python

Tags: python, thrift

In my project, I have to user build server and client in different language by integrate thrift to the project. So I decided to build client in python. However I know very little about python :(

So can anyone help to solve this simple problem

Assume that I have a class with those properties:

```
struct Exam {
    1:i64 examId,
    2:string student,
    3:i64 graded
}
```

In my server size, I have implement that code that return a list. So how can I read the the name of student from each exam in my client side (python).

I have tried this:

```
mylist = readExam();
print(mylist)     # This display correctly

#Integrate the list and get the student name
for i in mylist
   print "student: " % mylist.student
```

Comment: `i.student` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just what you are printing when iterating through `mylist`. For loops in python work similarly to foreach loops in java and other languages: the i takes on the value of each iterable in mylist in turn.  `mylist` is just a list of exams (e.g. think array list).

So you want:

```
for i in mylist:
   print "student: %s" % i.student
```

Or, in python 3 friendly code:

```
for i in mylist:
   print("student: %s" % i.student)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see here, the mistake is in the second `print`. Try using:

```
print("student: %s") i
```

or

```
print("student: " + i)
```

Both should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `vars()`, it gives object's attributes as a dictionnary:

> vars([object]) -> dictionary
>
> Without arguments, equivalent to `locals()`.
>
> With an argument, equivalent to `object.__dict__`.

Example:

```
>>> class MyObj(object):
...    pass
>>> obj = MyObj()
>>> vars(obj)
{}
>>> obj.a = 1
>>> vars(obj)
{'a': 1}
```